# Python passing decimal values with comma's to a postgresql function

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have a postgresql function which needs decimal/numeric values as variables.
The variables come from a database which holds decimal values with comma's as delimeters.
Problem i have is that de postgresql-function now reads these comma's as a delimeter for the different variables.

This is my psql-function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.controldubbel2(_datum date, _naamtegen character varying, _tegenrekening character varying, _omschrijving character varying, _bedrag numeric, _saldo numeric, _code character varying)
 RETURNS TABLE(bestaat boolean)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" WHERE "DATUM"=_datum
    AND "TEGENREKENING_IBAN_BBAN"=_tegenrekening AND
    "NAAM_TEGENPARTIJ"=_naamtegen AND "Omschrijving_1"=_omschrijving AND
    "BEDRAG"=_bedrag AND "saldo"=_saldo AND "CODE"=_code) as bestaat
LIMIT 1;
END
$function$
```

This is my python code to execute the function:

```
cursor.execute(f"SELECT controldubbel2('{datum2}', '{tegenrekening}', '{naamtegen}', '{omschrijving1}', '{bedrag}', '{saldo}', '{code}')")
```

Error i get:

```
ERROR: cannot cast type record to numeric 
LINE 1: SELECT controldubbel2('2023-01-05'::date,'DL453453530005300114'::varchar,'HALTEST'::varchar,'Naam: John Doe'::varchar,10,00::numeric, 23686,98::numeric, 'GT'::varchar)
SQL state: 42846
```

The problem is the comma's in the numeric values i believe.

Thnx in advanced.

Comment: **Do not build SQL queries with string formatting.** Use parameterized queries.

Comment: Your code is prone to SQL injection, and this is already happing. Another issue is your python code using comma's for decimals. By the way, you don't need a plpgsql function for a simple function like this, SQL would be good enough and (slightly) faster

Comment: Does the input for this function, come from a record in another table? If so, how come this data is using a comma for decimals? Wrong data type?

Comment: I export from a banking-portal to an excel-file. The amount (money) is exported as comma delemited decimal). The importing from excel to psql works well. But when adding rows from a new excel-file wanna check for existing rows. So there the comma delemited values come from.

Comment: When using varchar or text for numbers, any input would be acceptable. But once you try to use this input as a number, you have a problem. Export from excel using a dot instead of a comma and change your data type. You could also update your data to fix the problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @user2357112 mentioned, use parametrized queries:

```
saldo = float(saldo.replace(",", "."))

bedrag= float(bedrag.replace(",", "."))
```

cursor.execute("SELECT controldubbel2(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (datum2, tegenrekening, naamtegen, omschrijving1, bedrag, saldo, code))

Comment: Why is this better than using f-strings?

Comment: This avoids SQL injection, the problem you are facing by concatenating strings. You should use the right data type in each instance. You are performing an ETL process by moving data from Excel to DB and Excel again. Focus on the T:Transform

Comment: Better then `f` strings because they lead to SQL injection per ageless cartoon [Bobby Tables](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/Little_Bobby_Tables) and the original cartoon [bobby-tables.com](https://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Too bad, it didn't work. Changed to:

  cursor.execute('CALL controldubbel2(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', (datum2, tegenrekening, naamtegen, omschrijving1, bedrag, saldo, code))

But that didn't help.
When i change the input manually and change the comma to a period in the number-values than the query runs and outputs "false" which means there are no same rows. So that is good. So the problem is really the comma's in the numbers. I need them to be numeric and not as text otherwise i can't do no math with the numbers.

Comment: what is the issue? data type? what of those parameters are numbers?

Comment: _bedrag and _saldo are numbers.
In my database and in the excel-file they have the format for example: 10,00 and 22,00

Comment: use `saldo = float(saldo.replace(",", "."))` See the edit

Comment: Hello Horaciux. Thnx for the reply. 

With that code i change the comma to a dot in my python sql-query. 
Problem is that in the database the values hold comma's. So my query than finds no existing rows because it looks for numbers with dots, but there aren't any.

Comment: I think i gonna change my database and change the comma's to periods in my number-values.

Comment: that would be the correct approach.

Comment: When i try to replace the comma to a dot with: 

saldo = float(saldo.replace(",", "."))

I get:

'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: so saldo is not a string but a float64? I'm confuse

Comment: When i debug my python file i see that the variable _saldo and _bedrag are of type float64 and the values are with a dot. But when i save these values to the database they are formatted with an comma (just like in the excel-file)

Comment: what data type is that field? collation? Add table schema to post

Comment: Can i contact you tommorow? 
The comma / dot issue was solved by this :   

saldo = numpy.format_float_positional(saldo)
saldo = Decimal(saldo)

Changed float64 to string and then to decimal.

Everything works now, but it only works when using f-strings in my python coding.
When i use:

cursor.execute('CALL controldubbel2(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', (datum2, naamtegen, tegenrekening, omschrijving1, bedrag, saldo, code))

It gives error it can't cast the right types.